# Unix awk command to execute a specific logic

Tags: unix, awk, csplit

I am not so good with Unix commands and struggling to achieve this.

I have a file like below

**INPUT**

```
ABCDEF_XY_12345_PQRTS_67367
1,a,b,c1
2,a,b,c2
3,a,b,c3
.....
APRTEYW_XY_23456_GDJHJH_232434
1,a,b,c4
2,a,b,c5
3,a,b,c6
......
GDHGJHG_XY_35237_FHDJFH_738278
1,a,b,c7
2,a,b,c8
3,a,b,c9
......
```

**OUTPUT**

```
12345,1,a,b,c1
12345,2,a,b,c2
12345,3,a,b,c3
23456,1,a,b,c4
23456,2,a,b,c5
23456,3,a,b,c6
35237,1,a,b,c7
35237,2,a,b,c8
35237,3,a,b,c9
```

Essentially, taking substring between `_XY_[<STRING>]_` and prepending them to following lines like `<STRING>,1,a,b,c1` until we encounter a string matching pattern `_XY_[<STRING>]_` and then repeat the same process till EOF.

I am trying to find an easy way to do it either using `awk` or splitting the master file to multiple smaller files. Can you pls in the correct direction?

Comment: It is always recommended to add your efforts in your post. Also by seeing your profile came to know that you hardly select any answer as correct one. So give it sometime and when you see few answers to your question, try to select anyone of them as correct one out of them.

Comment: Please check [someone-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  and  [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). You can give a kind of closure to your questions, current one, or those old ones, all of them, and it benefits yourself too.

Comment: If those `......` lines don't actually exist in your real input then get rid of them from your sample input as all they do is obfuscate your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `awk` with multiple delimiter

```
awk -F"[_,]" -v OFS=, ' { if(/_/) { k=$3 } else { print k,$0 } } ' file
```

Thanks @EdMorton, single delimiter is enough

```
awk -F_ -v OFS=, ' { if(/_/) { k=$3 } else { print k,$0 } } ' file
```

it can be further shortened as

```
awk -F_ -v OFS=, ' /_/ {k=$3;next} { print k,$0 } ' file
```

with your given inputs

```
$ cat filex.txt
ABCDEF_XY_12345_PQRTS_67367
1,a,b,c1
2,a,b,c2
3,a,b,c3
APRTEYW_XY_23456_GDJHJH_232434
1,a,b,c4
2,a,b,c5
3,a,b,c6
GDHGJHG_XY_35237_FHDJFH_738278
1,a,b,c7
2,a,b,c8
3,a,b,c9

$ awk -F_ -v OFS=, ' { if(/_/) { k=$3 } else { print k,$0 } } ' filex.txt
12345,1,a,b,c1
12345,2,a,b,c2
12345,3,a,b,c3
23456,1,a,b,c4
23456,2,a,b,c5
23456,3,a,b,c6
35237,1,a,b,c7
35237,2,a,b,c8
35237,3,a,b,c9

$
```

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following once.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="_";OFS=","}/^[a-zA-Z]+/{val=$3;next} !/^\..*\.$/{print val,$0}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** In case place of `XY` string is NOT fixed in line then try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="_"
  OFS=","
}
/^[a-zA-Z]+/ && match($0,/XY_[0-9]+_/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-4)
  next
}
!/^\..*\.$/{
  print val,$0
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: @user1637487, could you please let me know if these codes have helped you?